# Memory over-release problem when I am animating UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, exc-bad-access

I have enabled NSZombie's and I am getting the following message in my console when I am running my application:

```
 *** -[UIViewAnimationState release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xf96d7e0
```

Here is the method that is performing the animation

```
-(void)loadAvatar:(STObject*)st
{   
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];    

    avatar.alpha = 0;
    avatar.frame = avatarRectSmall;

    avatar.image = [ImageCache getMemoryCachedImageAtUrl:st.avatar_url];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.50];

    avatar.frame = avatarRectNormal;
    [avatar setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];


    [pool release];
    pool = nil;
}
```

I don't always get a crash, only sometimes. I'm wondering what is getting released?

Comment: The backtrace only lets me go back to main. Anything after that is all assembly.

Comment: Try setting some breakpoints.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have an autorelease pool there which prompts me to ask, is this a separate thread? If the answer is yes then you can't do stuff to UIView there. UIKit is not thread safe. You can do other things like calculating positions or updating images which you later put on the screen but any user interface stuff has to happen in the main thread.

[Graphics and Drawing section of iPhone Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/GraphicsandDrawing/GraphicsandDrawing.html)

Comment: You are correct, this is a separate thread. I just want to load an image from a URL in my UIImageView. If I remove the animation code, it will only load the images sometimes.

Comment: Do you specifically need a separate thread for loading an image from a URL? Why not just use an async NSURLConnection or some other class with a delegate pattern?

Answer (score 6):

You can use very simple security check fof all functions doing something with UI:

```
-(void)functionModifyingUIelements:(id)object
{
 // fire itself in main thread if it is not in it already
 if (![[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]) { 

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(functionModifyingUIelements:) withObject:object waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }

}
```